# Differential equation error : Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function \ within specified tolerances

Tags: differential-equations

I am currently working on a Physics problem and have met a problem. The differential equation meets error

'NDSolve::icfail: Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function within specified tolerances. Try giving initial conditions for both values and derivatives of the functions.'

Constants

```
m = 0.004;
r = 0.005;
l = 0.04;
R = 0.01;
L = 0.005;
\[Mu] = 0.38;
\[Rho] = m/(Pi (r^2 l + R^2 L));
g = 9.78;
\[Phi] = ArcSin[70/186];
\[Alpha] = ArcTan[(R - r)/l];
Imid = 1/2 \[Rho] Pi (l r ^4 + L R^4);
A = 0.678396;
B = -4.77246;
R0 = r Cot[\[Alpha]] + l + (R^2 L^2 - r^2 l^2)/(2 (r^2 l + R^2 L));
\[Beta] = (R^2 L^2 - r^2 l^2)/(2 (r^2 l + R^2 L));
Iorth = 1/
   12 \[Rho] Pi (r^2 l (3 r^2 + l^2 + 
        3 ((R^2 L (L + l))/(r^2 l + R^2 L))^2) + 
     R^2 L (3 R^2 + L^2 + 3 ((r^2 l (L + l))/(r^2 l + R^2 L))^2));
```

System of differential equations

````
sol = NDSolve[{N1[t] + N2[t] == m g Cos[\[Phi]],
   
   -f1r[t]*(l + \[Beta]) - f2r[t]*\[Beta] == 
    Iorth*((Cos[\[Alpha]] (\[Theta]2''[t]*
             Cos[\[Theta]2[t]/2] - (\[Theta]2'[t])^2*0.5*
             Sin[\[Theta]2[t]/2]) + (0.5*Cos[\[Alpha]]*
            Sin[\[Theta]2[t]/
              2]*(\[Theta]2'[t]*Cos[\[Alpha]]*Cos[\[Theta]2[t]/2])^2/
             1 - (Cos[\[Alpha]]*Sin[\[Theta]2[t]/2])^2))/Sqrt[
       1 - (Cos[\[Alpha]]*Sin[\[Theta]2[t]/2])^2]),
   f1[t] == Sqrt[(\[Mu]*N1[t])^2 - (f1r[t])^2], 
   f2[t] == Sqrt[(\[Mu]*N2[t])^2 - (f2r[t])^2],
   x''[t] == 
    g*Sin[\[Phi]] - \[Mu]*g*Cos[\[Phi]]*x'[t]/
      Sqrt[(x'[t])^2 + (y'[t])^2],
   y''[t] == -\[Mu]*g*Cos[\[Phi]]*y'[t]/Sqrt[(x'[t])^2 + (y'[t])^2],
   f1r[t] == \[Mu]*
     N1[t]*(Sin[\[Theta]2[t]]*x'[t]/Sqrt[(x'[t])^2 + (y'[t])^2] - 
       Cos[\[Theta]2[t]]*y'[t]/Sqrt[(x'[t])^2 + (y'[t])^2]),
   f2r[t] == \[Mu]*
     N2[t]*(Sin[\[Theta]2[t]]*x'[t]/Sqrt[(x'[t])^2 + (y'[t])^2] - 
       Cos[\[Theta]2[t]]*y'[t]/Sqrt[(x'[t])^2 + (y'[t])^2]),
   (N1[t] + N2[t])*R0*Cos[\[Alpha]]*(f1[t] + f2[t])*R0*
     sin[\[Alpha]] == 
    r*Csc[\[Alpha]]*(N1[t] + N2[t]) + N2[t]*l*Sec[\[Alpha]],
   \[Theta]2[0] == A, \[Theta]2'[0] == B, 
   x[0] == R0*Cos[\[Alpha]]*Cos[A], y[0] == R0*Cos[\[Alpha]]*Sin[A], 
   x'[0] == -R0*B*Cos[\[Alpha]]*Sin[A], 
   y'[0] == R0*B*Cos[\[Alpha]]*Cos[A], N1[0] == 0.0117546, 
   N2[0] == 0.0244893,}, {N1, N2, f1, f2, f1r, f2r, \[Theta]2, x, 
   y}, {t, 0, 10}]
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started, 1) take the introductory [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Good news:  the DEs for `x[t]` and `y[t]` uncouple from the other DEs and `NDSolve` can get an expression for those two functions.  Bad news:  that leaves nonlinear system of DAEs, which `NDSolve` can't solve (as far as I know).  Possible approach:  Keep only your 2nd, 5th and 6th equations.  Use 7th & 8th equations to eliminate `f1r` and `f2r` from 2nd equation.  However, there are also a few typos:  `sin` in 8th equation should be `Sin`, the comma at the end of the equation list, and the 2nd equation has `/1`, which is not necessarily wrong, but division by one needs to be confirmed.